# Wired connection connected, but no internet access

Tags: 13.04, networking, internet, wired

I have HP Compaq nx6310 Laptop and I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on it. I have a TP-Link WR720N Router connected to another system running on Windows 8 Pro. The problem is I can connect to the router but internet access is not available on my Ubuntu system, but works fine with Windows. Please help me in this regard.

The output of `ifconfig`:

```
saumya@saumya-HP-Compaq-nx6310:~$ ifconfig
eth1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:08:30:43:9b
        inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
        inet6 addr: fe80::217:8ff:fe30:439b/64 Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:674 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:106 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:125357 (125.3 KB)  TX bytes:21771 (21.7 KB)
        Interrupt:16

lo      Link encap:Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
        RX bytes:47392 (47.3 KB)  TX bytes:47392 (47.3 KB)
```

The output of `iwconfig`:

```
saumya@saumya-HP-Compaq-nx6310:~$ iwconfig
lo      no wireless extensions.

eth1    no wireless extensions.
```

The output of `nm-tool`:

```
saumya@saumya-HP-Compaq-nx6310:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth1  [Wired connection 1] -----------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            b44
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        00:17:08:30:43:9B

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.101
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             8.8.8.8
    DNS:             4.2.2.2
```

The output of `ping -c2 192.168.0.1`:

```
saumya@saumya-HP-Compaq-nx6310:~$ ping -c2 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.445 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.158 ms

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.158/0.301/0.445/0.144 ms
```

The output of `ping -c2 4.2.2.2`:

```
saumya@saumya-HP-Compaq-nx6310:~$ ping -c2 4.2.2.2
PING 4.2.2.2 (4.2.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: icmp_req=1 ttl=46 time=446 ms
64 bytes from 4.2.2.2: icmp_req=2 ttl=46 time=280 ms

--- 4.2.2.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 280.625/363.365/446.105/82.740 ms
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `nm-tool` to your question?

Comment: [Edit] your question, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), write the following commands and paste the output of: `ifconfig`, `iwconfig`, `nm-tool`.

Comment: @Braiam I have added the required outputs of `ifconfig`, `iwconfig` and `nm-tool`. Please help me.

Comment: @Mitch added the required outputs. Please help.

Comment: It seems your system is configured with a ip 192.168.0.101 and routers is 192.168.0.1. Try to setup new connection using edit connections option and add the relevant details there or either your router is blocking internet access as you are able to connect with it.

Comment: @Tarun how to do that? Please clarify the detailed steps.

Comment: Can you add `ping -c2 192.168.0.1` and `ping -c2 4.2.2.2`?

Comment: here is a link it will be helpful http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-a-Network-in-Ubuntu

Comment: @Braiam I have added the required outputs of `ping -c2 192.168.0.1` and `ping -c2 4.2.2.2`. Please help me.

Comment: Can _anyone_ please help me with my problem listed?

Comment: @Braiam please help me.

Comment: @Tarun the thing did not work. Please help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your system is able to connect to the router but not to the internet. After seeing the outputs above you are able to ping both your router and dns. That means either your firewall is blocking the connection or you need to check from the router. Everything else seems fine.